# Chromecast Web Sender api: switch audio track

Tags: chromecast

I have streams that contains multiple audio tracks and I'd like to provide a way to users so they can change the audio.

Does Chromecast web sender api has such functionality?

If not, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is supported by APIs, read our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender), specially the section "Using the Tracks APIs". Note that our Default an Styled receivers only support multiple Text Tracks but you can write your own receiver to support multiple Audio Tracks with the provided APIs.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for Audio Tracks. Unfortunately, as you pointed out, I would have to create a custom receiver.

Comment: To effectively use those Tracks APIs, the sender would have to parse manifest of a stream to get the required information, but chromecast default receiver doesn't already do that?

Comment: When the tracks info (audio or text) is in the manifest, MPL parses that in our Default/Styled receivers; we don't even see the manifest on the sender side in many cases.

Comment: So default receiver parses it. There should be an api method like `media.getAudioTracks()` that returns all the available audio tracks. And if the sender wants to change the audio track, it can pass an index or something...

Comment: It is the MPL that parses that.

Comment: would you mind explain what is MPL you're talking about?

Comment: Media Player Library (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/) that handles all the adaptive media formats, etc.